# Setting up school wifi network with SSO linked to azure AD without local server

Tags: networking, firewall, ldap, wifi, entra-id

I am trying to restrict school Wi-Fi usage to staff and students. In addition would like to get user-wise usage data. Our current Wi-Fi network and access points are built on Cisco Access points and switches. All the users use common wifi at the moment and we are unable to track usage. In an ideal case, we want them to log in with their school ID(Office 365/Azure AD) and we want to track their data usage and restrict access to a few sites. We have come across certain firewalls that require yearly licences for the restriction part but we are trying to implement a cheaper solution to handle more than 400 users. And we don't have a solution to directly connect with the Active directories to create Wi-Fi authentication. Ideally, if there is a device that does both that would be great. Since this is a Non-Profit school cheap solutions will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have on-prem MS-AD then you can provision a RADIUS server as an authentication bridge between your APs and MS-AD.

Filtering is a bit more complicated.

There are several open source implementations of AUP enforcement based on squid (Google SquidGuard). But these are dependant on enforcing access via the proxy.

It's also possible to MITM SSL connections - this is how a lot of commercial offerings work. However this is a massive can of worms regarding privacy. Again it can be done with open-source software. Even if you had a huge budget, you need to consider the ramifications of implementing this.

The simplest approach (although far from watertight) is to run a filtered DNS service.

Comment: The MS-AD still need a licence plus maintaining a server is a challenge. Ideally, if it is a one-time setup I can get it approved

Comment: Going from a cloud-based to hybrid MS-AD is probably a retrograde step - and may have a limited lifespan. AD in the cloud does not provide LDAP (last time I checked) so you would need to go buy some thing or setup freeeRadius with (e.g.) https://github.com/jimdigriz/freeradius-oauth2-perl